# How to create an algorithm to reorder a list with a given radius, ensuring no elements within the radius r remain in close proximity after reordering

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have been struggling with this question where I need to create an algorithm to handle an array and a given radius *r*. The algorithm should rearrange the elements in such a way that each element at index *i* is not within the radius of its immediately preceding or succeeding elements.

For example the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] where *r* = 2
for element 1 on index 0 it can not be in range of 2 or 3
for element 2 on index 1 it can not be in range of 1, 3 or 4
for element 3 on index 2 it can not be in range of 1, 2, 4 or 5
and so on...

if this is impossible return the array with most elements that fulfill the condition

How can I approach solving this problem efficiently?

I've tried to find similar leetcode questions, tried to find similar posts here, reddit and youtube. But with no luck.

I know you could probably make a brute force algorithm for this but that will be really inefficient and slow.

Comment: Will the elements always be in ascending order? Unique? Same/non-decreasing difference between any two successive elements? If not, please improve example.

Comment: @DillonDavis brought up that element values may be intended as *identifiers*: I suggest to use letters in the example in this case. (What about *equal* identifiers?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is optimal, but it seems to be for the inputs that I've tried.  Slice the list, taking every n'th element to be part of the same continuous "chunk" of the output array, where `n = radius + 1`. Then order these chunks by decreasing stagger/offset.

```py
def reorder(elems, radius):
    output = []
    for offset in range(radius, -1, -1):
        output.extend(elems[offset::radius+1])
    return output
```

When the length of the list is twice the radius or longer, the above algorithm will definitely return an optimal result.

I'll give it some more thought later, and see if I can prove/disprove its overall optimality.

Comment: (This seems to assume the input is "a range", or strictly increasing with delta ≥ 1. *Why* not just `range(radius)`?)

Comment: @greybeard good catch. By "not within the radius of its immediately preceding or succeeding elements" I assumed they meant with respect to their position in the original array, not by element value.  So `[a, b, c, ..., x, y, z]` would get permuted in fixed fashion regardless of the element values.  This might not be what OP meant, however.

Comment: Regarding why to use `range(radius, -1, -1)` over `range(radius)`, consider the values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` with radius 2. In ascending offset, this would be `[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]`, or `[0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]` when flattened- the difference between the largest value in one "chunk" and the smallest value in the next "chunk" (adjacent elements) is `radius`. If we instead order by decreasing offset, we get `[(2, 5), (1, 4), (0, 3)]`, or differences of `radius+2`, meaning every adjacent element is at least `radius+1` apart.